# macOS find command behaving strangely

Tags: bash, macos, find

Example of command as used in bash script:

```
find '/Files' -type d -name temp* -depth -delete -print
```

This command should delete all folders, whose names start with "temp" in '/Files' folder and its subfolders ("temp0", "temp1", "temp2" etc.).

Script is working as expected, folders are found and properly deleted.

But sometimes, for some users, on some computers etc. script is not working as expected, despite the fact that folders & files are exactly the same.

Find command fails like this:

```
find /Files -type d -name tempta temptal -depth -delete -print
find: temptal: unknown primary or operator
```

I can't find out where "tempta" and "temptal" are coming - i don't have files with that names anywhere in the folder. Temp* folders are present, but not deleted because of this error.

The only thing which might be connected, are two files named "AbcInstall.sh" and "AbcInstall.log" in "AbcTemp" subfolder. So we have "ta" and "tal" plus "Temp". These are elements which reminds on "tempta" and "temptal", but they make no real sense - it could be a coincidence.

How can "find" result resolve into something like this !?!

Sorry for the lack of better explanation - this problem is really weird. The problem is that i can't replicate this issue on my computer so all i can do is experimenting (so far without success).

Any hints or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Thx!

Comment: `-name 'temp*'` - you don't want the shell to glob that

Comment: You should quote `temp*`, otherwise it'll expand to the filenames starting with `temp` in current working directory.

Comment: You'd also get "strange" results if you have the `failglob` or `nullglob` settings enabled.

Comment: You have some additional constructs that may give you misleading results. First, you delete, then you print. This will end up printing all directory names, not just ones that are deleted (if that's what you want). Second, this deletes only empty directories, and to be more explicit I'd include `-empty` if that's what you want. Third, I think I'd put `-depth` first as it is a global option that always returns true and affects tests that come earlier (see the man page for a better explanation).

Comment: The other comments are suggesting you use `find ... -name temp\* ...` or `find ... -name 'temp*' ...`

Comment: This has nothing to do with macOS or `find`; it's expected shell behavior.

Comment: If by 'strange behaviour' you mean more than just this one example you could also look at using the gnu version of `find` instead of the macos version, e.g. https://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: Thanks everybody for very helpful answers. Now i understand quotes are required in my case - i changed script and sent it to user for testing. I am sure it will work now, will keep you informed anyway. So this "misbehaviour" is completely my fault, not related to macos and find etc. Just caused by a lack of knowledge about bash, globbing etc.